# Expire post after expiry date

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have been searching on how to expire posts after an expiry date - Ive tried a few plugins, but they only seem to work on articles posts in posts.

Im using ACF and have a group called 'Event Group', within the group I have a fields called 'expiry_date'

The date saves in the format of 'Ymd'

I was trying to get the code to run as a daily cron, but its not working so the code now triggers when activating the plugin (when its working I can focus on the cron element)

I have the below code:

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Auto Expire Events
Description: Automatically sets events to 'draft' after the expiry date.
Version: 1.0
Author: Dave
*/

// Exit if accessed directly.
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}

// Function to check and update event status.
function check_and_update_event_status() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'event', // Change this to your custom post type.
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'expiry_date', // Change this to the ACF field name.
                'value'   => date('Ymd'),    // Adjust format according to 'Ymd'.
                'compare' => '<',
                'type'    => 'DATE',          // Change type to 'DATE'.
            ),
        ),
    );

    $expired_events = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($expired_events->have_posts()) {
        while ($expired_events->have_posts()) {
            $expired_events->the_post();
            $event_id = get_the_ID();

            // Update event status to 'draft'.
            wp_update_post(array('ID' => $event_id, 'post_status' => 'draft'));
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}

// Schedule the function to run once, immediately after activation.
function schedule_auto_expire_event_on_activation() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('auto_expire_event')) {
        wp_schedule_single_event(time(), 'auto_expire_event');
    }
}

// Hook to run the function on scheduled event.
add_action('auto_expire_event', 'check_and_update_event_status');

// Schedule the event on plugin activation.
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'schedule_auto_expire_event_on_activation');

// Clear the scheduled event on plugin deactivation.
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'wp_clear_scheduled_hook', 'auto_expire_event');
```

Anything blatently obvious thats incorrect within my code? Or a better way to test and identify an issue?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's a syntax issue in your `register_deactivation_hook`. It should be something like:

```
function clear_auto_expire_event_schedule() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('auto_expire_event');
}
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'clear_auto_expire_event_schedule');
```